# Angular save template state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a routing:

```
  $stateProvider
     .state('work-monitor', {
          url: '/work-monitor',
          templateUrl: 'templates/work-monitor.html',
     })
    ;
```

In template I have timers, google map etc. Is there any option to save template state ? When I change route and go back the template is reloaded, I want load template only once.

Comment: It depends on exactly what kinds of things you want to save for re-use later on. You could create yourself an angular service\factory and save some values in there when the route change start event is fired for the state you want to save some information about. Then when you come back to the state later on, read the values back out of your service in your state template's controller

Comment: I have a google map with markers, paths etc (like in navigation) so I want do store it all.

Comment: Ok, so if you want to reload the same set of markers at which ever position they were at, any paths drawn, etc, then I still would suggest you look into using an angular service to store these all for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try it

Comment: For small app as temporary solution, you can just add this map to root state and show/hide it.